# need JPA method for below query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i need only years of my "Expensive" table "date" feild
date data is "2023-01-01","2022-01-01" etc
need only list of years with desc order [2023,2022]

```
@Query(value="SELECT DISTINCT DATE_PART('year', CAST(e.date AS DATE)) AS years " +
            "FROM Expensive e WHERE e.user_id = :userId AND e.date IS NOT NULL ORDER BY years DESC", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Integer> findDistinctYears(Long userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know which RDBMS you are actually using, but `DATE_PART()` does look to be native SQL of some flavor.  However, since it appears you were storing text dates, you could just use JPQL here with `SUBSTRING()`:

```java
@Query(value="SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(e.date, 1, 4) AS years " +
             "FROM Expensive e WHERE e.user_id = :userId AND e.date IS NOT NULL " +
             "ORDER BY SUBSTRING(e.date, 1, 4) DESC")
List<Integer> findDistinctYears(Long userId);
```

Comment: The answer I have given in fact uses `@Query` with valid JPA syntax.

Comment: is its possible without @Query annotation ? im checking with direct JPA method